# "做學問" in English?

Tags: phrase

This question is about the translation of "做學問" in English.

If I am asked to translate "做學問", then I would say "doing research". But somehow I feel that such translation of mine is insufficient to characterize the spirit of "做學問".

Therefore, I have to solicit some opinions and ideas on this issue. Thanks.

Comment: engage in scholarship?

Comment: Thanks. Well, I have googled it but found nearly nothing satisfactory. :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following:

**A Chinese-English Dictionary**

> engage in scholarship; do research
>
> 他是做学问的人, 不会做买卖。
>
> Tā shì zuò xuéwèn de rén, bù huì zuò mǎimai.
>
> He's **a scholar** and no businessman.

**ABC**

> engage in scholarly work
>
> 他是个做学问的人。
>
> Tā shì ge zuò xuéwen de rén.
>
> He's capable of **scholarly** work.

**Oxford** (Pocket)

> engage in scholarship, do research

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest "engage in academic pursuit", as 學問 is what academia is all about.